# How to create random relationships between nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create random transaction between bank accounts. I have created the following query:

```
//Create transactions
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
match (a:BANK_ACCOUNT)
WITH apoc.coll.randomItem(collect(a)) as sender
return sender", "
MATCH (b:BANK_ACCOUNT)
WHERE NOT sender = b
WITH apoc.coll.randomItem(collect(b)) as receiver
MERGE (sender)-[r:HAS_TRANSFERED {time: datetime()}]->(receiver)
set r.amount = rand()*1000",
{batchSize:100, parallel:false});
```

I would assume that it would create 100 random transactions between random bank accounts. Instead it creates 1 new bank account and 1 new relationship. What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query uses [apoc.coll.randomItems](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/data-structures/collection-list-functions/) to get 200 different random accounts at one time (which is much faster than getting one random account 200 times):

```
MATCH (ba:BankAccount)
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(COLLECT(ba), 200) AS accts
WHERE SIZE(accts) > 1 
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(accts)/2*2-1, 2) AS i
WITH accts[i] AS sender, accts[i+1] AS receiver
CREATE (sender)-[:TRANSFERED_TO {time: datetime()}]->(receiver)
```

Notes:

1. This query uses `CREATE` instead of `MERGE` because it is unlikely that a `TRANSFERED_TO` relationship already exists with the current time as the `time` value. (You can choose to use `MERGE` anyway, if duplication is still possible.)
2. The `WHERE SIZE(accts) > 1` test avoids errors when there are not at least 2 accounts.
3. `SIZE(accts)/2*2-1` calculation prevents the [RANGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-range) function from generating a list index (`i`) that exceeds the last valid index for a `sender` account.